# Android service seems to be getting paused when screen is off

Tags: java, android, android-service, thread-sleep

I have an android service that pulls updates from a server every 5 minutes. It works great when the screen is on, but when it is off it seems to pause. Keep in mind the service runs in the foreground using start foreground().

I am currently creating a new Thread and having it sleep in order to run the update every 5 minutes, is there a better method that would allow the timer to still run while the device is sleeping?

Comment: "I am currently creating a new Thread and having it sleep in order to run the update every 5 minutes" -- please don't waste your users' system RAM just to watch the clock tick. "is there a better method that would allow the timer to still run while the device is sleeping?" -- please use `AlarmManager`, along with either the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` or `WakefulIntentService` patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alarm via AlarmManager.  The alarm will wake the CPU, allowing you to do your processing.  If you're just waiting on a sleep in a thread, you won't be waken if the phone is off (its in sleep mode).

Of course you'll need a background thread or task to do the actual downloading.  That's where a wakelock comes in.  When the alarm goes off, request a wakelock.  When you're done checking/downloading, release it.  For your case, you can keep the same architecture-  just instead of a 5 minute sleep waiting to recheck, wait on a semaphore.  When the alarm comes in, request a wakelock and signal the semaphore.  When the check is done, release the wakelock and semaphore, then wait on it again.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to accomplish it without the semaphore. I read a bit on them but I am still not sure what purpose it would serve. Could you clarify that?

Comment: If you have a thread that wants to wait for an event, you wait on a semaphore.  Then the part of the code that sees the event releases the semaphore.  This will wake up the other thread and allow it to run.  This way the code can only run after an event occurs.  There are of course other ways to do it as well, its just one common and efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

The update isn't happening because the phone is going to sleep when you turn off the screen. Happens more often on WiFi if "Optimized WiFi" mode is turned on.

You should have a look at [wakelocks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html). Acquire a wakelock to prevent device from falling asleep. Release it to let it sleep again. Note that this obviously increases battery consumption.